# How to download a file from specific directory using php header

Tags: php, header

I have some code to download file using php header but it is not properly working and want to add directory to read

```
    <?php
if(isset($_GET['link'])){
    $var_1 = $_GET['link'];
$dir='/upload/';
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['link'])){
    $var_1 = $_GET['link'];
$file = $var_1;
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
echo "<h1>Content error</h1><p>The file does not exist!</p>";
}
?>
```

It shows error 
Content error

The file does not exist!

I am Using

> http://sap.layyah.info/download.php?link=UAC.dll

this link to download the file file original location is

> http://sap.layyah.info/upload/UAC.dll

Comment: Sidenote: Change `$file = '$var_1';` to `$file = $var_1;`

Comment: You're also missing a `}` at the end\

Comment: it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/u723533513/public_html/download.php on line 19

Comment: look at my comment. That is why formatting helps

Comment: See what  ElefantPhace  said.

Comment: error remoded but file is not starting download

Comment: and how to add directory to read

Comment: We need to know how you're using this, from a form? A hyperlink? Plus, what do you mean by "add a directory to read"?

Comment: You shouldn't follow the comments/examples from php.net regarding readfile() which is exactly where that came from. There are many other better examples out there. I personally use the XSendFile header using apache.

Comment: i am using it like hyper link and my location of files are different then download.php

Comment: This `$file = $var_1;` could be something like `$dir="folder/"; $file = $dir$var_1;` or `$dir="../folder/"; $file = $dir$var_1;` depending on the folder's location.

Comment: @Fred-ii- don't forget to concat those two variables!

Comment: Doh! lol You're right, I forgot the dot `$file = $dir . $var_1;` @ElefantPhace Thanks (*Tired eyes*). I will rephrase for the OP.

Comment: This `$file = $var_1;` could be something like `$dir="folder/"; $file = $dir . $var_1;` or `$dir="../folder/"; $file = $dir . $var_1;` depending on the folder's location.

Comment: See my answer and also look for a working test under my **Edit** @user2740125

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, the quotes in `$file = '$var_1';` won't get interpreted correctly,

therefore it needs to read as `$file = $var_1;`

You also have a missing closing brace `}`

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['link']))
{
    $var_1 = $_GET['link'];
    $file = $var_1;

if (file_exists($file))
    {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    }
} //- the missing closing brace
?>
```

And you mentioned that you wanted to use a different folder.

You could use something to the effect of:

```
$dir = "folder/"; // trailing slash is important
$file = $dir . $var_1;
```

or

```
$dir = "../folder/"; // trailing slash is important
$file = $dir . $var_1;
```

depending on the folder's location.

---

### Edit

The following is tested and worked for me and the files were run from the root of my server.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['link']))
{
    $var_1 = $_GET['link'];
//    $file = $var_1;

$dir = "folder/"; // trailing slash is important
$file = $dir . $var_1;

if (file_exists($file))
    {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    }
} //- the missing closing brace
?>
```

**HTML** (I used a PDF file as an example)

```
<a href="download.php?link=document.pdf">Download here</a>
```

Comment: That's great news, glad to hear it. @user2740125 Glad to have helped.